# efficient indexing of an array

Tags: c

Suppose that I have

```
z[7]={0, 0, 2, 0, 1, 2, 1}
```

that means- first observation allocated in group 0, second obs group 0, third group 2 etc
and I want to write an efficient code to get an array of 3X? such that in the first row I have all the observations allocated in the first group, second row all the obs allocated in the second group etc.. something like

```
0, 1, 3
4, 6 
2, 5
```

and this must be general, maybe I could have

```
z={0, 0, 2, 0, 1, 2, 1, 3, 4, 2, 0, 4, 5, 5, 6, 7, 0}
```

so the number of columns is unknown

I did do my homework and the code is attached to this message, but there must be a better way to do it. I believe that with pointers but I really do not know how.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
  int z[7]={0, 0, 2, 0, 1, 2, 1}, nj[3], iz[3][7], ip[3], i, j;


for(j=0; j<3; j++){
    ip[j] = 0;
    nj[j] = 0;
  }

  for(i=0; i <7; i++ ){
    nj[z[i]] = nj[z[i]] + 1;
    iz[z[i]][ip[z[i]]] = i;
    ip[z[i]] = ip[z[i]] + 1;    
  }  

  for(j=0; j<3 ;j++){
    for(i=0; i < nj[j]; i++){
      printf("%d\t", iz[j][i]);
    }
    printf("\n");    
  }
  return 0;  
}
```

Comment: I think pointers and arrays in C/C++ really are the same thing. So rewriting your code to have "more pointers" and "less array accesses" is not going to bring any improvements apart from maybe looking fancier.

Comment: Which arrays have an unknown size or comes from the user and which are part of you solution? You could also explain the meaning of each variable you are using.

Comment: Optimizing array access can be a bit of a micro-optimization. I'd really only be concerned about this if it were shown to be performance critical.

Comment: BTW--Everything the other commentators have said here about the equivalence of array indexing and pointer math, premature optimization is true. You would be well served by re-writing the question to emphasize the need to dynamically size the data structure rather than some ill-defined notion of "efficiency".

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you have two tasks here.

1. To count the number of occurrences of each index in `z` and allocate a data structure of the right size and configuration.
2. To iterate over the data and copy it to the correct places.

At the moment you appear to have solved (1) naively by allocating a big, two dimensional array `iz`. That works fine if you know in advance the limits on how big it could be (and your machine will have enough memory), no need to fix this until later.

It is not clear to me exactly how (2) should be approached. Is the data currently going into `iz` guaranteed to consist of [0, 1, ... n ]?

---

If you *don't* know the limits of the size of `iz` in advance, then you will have to allocate a dynamic structure. I'd suggest a ragged array though this means two (or even three) passes over `z`.

What do I mean by a ragged array? A object like the `argv` argument to `main`, but in this case of type `int **`. In memory it looks like this:

```
+----+     +---+     +---+---+---+--
| iz |---->|   |---->|   |   |   ...
+----+     +---+     +---+---+---+--
           |   |--
           +---+  \    +---+---+---+--
           | . |   --->|   |   |   ...
             .         +---+---+---+--
             .
```

A ragged array can be accessed with `iz[][]` just like it was a two-dimensional array (but it is a different type of object), which is nice for your purposes because you can tune your algorithm with the code you have now, and then slap one of these in place.

---

How to set it up.

1. Iterate of `z` to find the largest number, `maxZ`, present.
2. Allocate an array of `int*` of size `maxZ+1`: `iz=callac(maxZ+1,sizeof(int*));`.

   I chose `calloc` because it zeros the memory, which makes all those pointers `NULL`, but you could use `malloc` and NULL them yourself. Making the array one too big gives us a NULL termination, which may be useful later.
3. Allocate an array of counters of size `maxZ`: `int *cz = calloc(maxZ,sizeof(int));`
4. iterate over `z`, filling `cz` with the number of entries needed in each row.
5. For each row, allocate an array of ints: `for(i=0; i<maxZ; ++i){ iz[i] = malloc(sizeof(int)*cz[i]; }`
6. Iterate over `z` one last time, sticking the figures into `iz` as you already do. You *could* re-use `cz` at this point to keep track of how many figure have already been put into each row, but you might want to allocate a separate array for that purpose because so that you have a record of how big each allocated array was.

**NB:** Every call to `malloc` or `calloc` ought to be accompanied by a check to insure that the allocation worked. I've left that as an exercise for the student.

---

This repeated passes over `z` business can be avoided entirely by using dynamic arrays, but I suspect you don't need that and don't want the added complexity.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think that indeed you can even define an array of int* where each row has different number of columns so if I calculate first the number of observations on each group int nj, then I could waste less memory. However I would have to do it on a different for